How to avoid explicit undefined check when passing string prop to component in TypeScript?
Is it possible to type the checkVar function so that an error does not occur?
TS2322: Type string | undefined is not assignable to type string?
// TestComponent accepts a string parameter fooProp.  
function TestComponent({ fooProp }: { fooProp: string }) {  
  // ... some actions with fooProp  
  return null;  
}  

// foo variable can be string or undefined.  
const foo = Math.random() > 0.5 ? 'foo value' : undefined;  

// Function checks presence of variable
const checkVar = (x: string | undefined): boolean => !!x;  

// If bar is undefined then checkVar(bar) is false  
if (checkVar(foo)) {  
  return <TestComponent fooProp={foo} />; // TS2322: Type string | undefined is not assignable to type string  
}

This is simplified code that may look artificial. I know that you can use type assertion or non-null assertion. This question is less about solving a specific problem and more about the capabilities of TypeScript.

Lots more answers via this search (not criticism; it's much easier to find this when you already know the name of what you're searching for. :-) ).

If you need a custom function, you need to use a type predicate
const checkVar = (x: string | undefined): x is string => !!x;  

Note that empty string is falsy in JS, thus checkVar("") returns false. If this is not what you expect, compare against undefined instead

All you need is a type predicate in order to verify that foo is not undefined. This is because TypeScripts control flow analysis cannot narrow variables over multiple function scopes.
function TestComponent({ fooProp }: { fooProp: string }) {
  return null;
}

const foo = Math.random() > 0.5 ? "foo value" : undefined;

function IsDefined(value: string | undefined): value is string {
  return value !== undefined;
}

function Parent() {
  if (IsDefined(foo)) {
    return <TestComponent fooProp={foo} />; 
  }
  
  return null;
}

TypeScript Playground

I'd refrain from checking with !!x as that will also return false on an empty string -- because the empty string "" is also a falsey. But that depends on your usecase. Maybe you want to exclude the empty string in your usecase. Adapt the check accordingly
But the real problem is, that your checkVar is a boolean function, but it should be a type predicate because typescript cannot use boolean function for type narrowing.
So I suggest using the following
function checkVar(cand: unknown): cand is string {
  return typeof cand === "string";
}

The important part in this snippet is the cand is string which makes this function a type predicate instead of the boolean function it would be if you don't add the return type ...
